# Cognos: Anonymous access and Single Sign On

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I am currently running:
Windows Server 2016
SQL Server 2016
IIS
Cognos Analytics 11.1.7
SSO
SSL
MS Active Directory

This is a single-server install, so the content manager, dispatcher, and gateway are all on one Windows machine.  On the ibmcognos application in IIS, Windows Authentication is enabled and Anonymous Authentication is disabled.  In Cognos Configuration, "Allow anonymous access?" is set to False.

I want to make my Cognos offering available on the Internet.  So I'm thinking I need "Allow anonymous access?" set to True and Anonymous Authentication is enabled.  But I'm sure it's more complicated than that.

Here's what I'm thinking:

- Add a Windows Server with IIS to my environment.
- Install Cognos gateway on the new server.
- Configure IIS for Cognos and allow anonymous authentication.
- Configure Cognos (gateway) to point to my existing system.
- Change "Allow anonymous access?" (on my existing system) to True.

For testing, can this all live on one server?

- Install Cognos gateway into a separate folder.
- Add a web site to the IIS web server.
- Configure the new web site to use the new gateway and anonymous authentication.

Is that it?  Is it that simple?

I know I'll need to adjust folder permissions in Team Content as appropriate to accommodate Everyone and still provide security.
I know there are risks concerning potential workloads on the Cognos server when I allow the entire planet access to it.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be simpler.  No additional install is needed.  All that is needed is to change "Allow anonymous access?" to True on my initial configuration and allow Anonymous Authentication in IIS.  Then all users get access to the objects that Everyone can see.  To get access to internal-only content, they must click on the `Personal menu` and select `Sign in`.  Not tested, but anyone not already authenticated in the Active Directory domain should get challenged for credentials.